# Hapi 2.1 version's MSH-9 filed concerns

Tags: hl7, hapi

I'm using Hapi release version 2.1 and it works perfectly. But I have an issue with an error response that I get from Hapi. My request is:

> MSH|^~\&|||||20130612174137.811+0530||OUL^R22^OUL_R22|2801|T|2.5

And my response is:

> MSH|^~\&|||||20130612174152.606+0530||ACK^R22^ACK|1624|T|2.5
>   MSA|AE|2801
>   ERR|||207^Application internal error^HL70357^^^^^^errmsg|E

In the above response, if you check the MSH-9 field, it is:

**ACK^R22^ACK**

Shouldn't that be "**ACK**"? Because it is additionally adding "**R22**" message to that field, which is not valid. And I suspect that it picks that from the original request.

Can anybody help me on this? How can I avoid that invalid segment?
Why does Hapi additionally add that field in the MSH-9 field?

Answer (score 0):

As the definition of the field MSH-9 in HL7 Version 2.5 is

```
<Message Code (ID)> ^ <Trigger Event (ID)> ^ <Message Structure (ID)>
```

this is a correct and valid implementation.

Maybe you can get an generic acknowledgement by using either an older message version in MSH-12 or by using an generic message template.